# Сформировать дерево из вложенных элементов

Tags: c#

В чем здесь ошибка? При обходе списка в целевой список попадают одинаковые элементы. А нужна древовидная, где первый элемент представляется как корень с нулевым idParent = 0; и далее по вложенности? У меня корректно формируется только первая цепочка узлов. Каждая строка представляет собой узел, который ссылается на своего родителя.

Вот исходная структура:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так структура выглядит в программном коде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот метод обхода:

```
public List<TreeViewElements> GetData()
        {
            var parser = new GetExcelData(Server.MapPath("~/Content/NewData.xlsx"));
            var listElements = parser.GetNew();
            var result = new List<TreeViewElements>();
            int unicId = 1;
            int statCID = -2;
            int count = 0;
            bool check;
            int parentId = 0;

            var sortedListElements = from e in listElements
                                     orderby e.ProgramName
                                     select e;

            foreach (var element in sortedListElements)
            {
                var names = new List<string>(new string[] { element.ProgramName, element.Progect, element.Budget, element.Stage,
                                                            element.SystemName, element.ObjectName, element.ISR.ToString(), element.PIR,
                                                            element.TaskName});

                count = 0;

                foreach (var name in names)
                {
                    if (count < 8) statCID = -2; // -2 - промежуточные элементы
                    else statCID = element.CID;

                    var nood = new TreeViewElements()
                    {
                        ID = unicId.ToString(),
                        Parent_ID = parentId.ToString(),
                        Name = name,
                        CID = statCID
                    };

                    check = true;

                    foreach (var item in result)
                    {
                        if (item.Name != nood.Name)
                        {
                            nood.Parent_ID = item.ID.ToString();
                        } else if (item.Name == nood.Name)
                        {
                            int idParent = Convert.ToInt32(nood.Parent_ID);

                            if (idParent == 0 || item.ID == nood.Parent_ID)
                            {
                                check = false;
                                break;
                            } else
                            {
                                nood.Parent_ID = item.ID;
                            }       
                        }
                    }

                    if (check)
                    {
                        result.Add(nood);
                        unicId++;
                    }

                    count++;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что то я ни задачу вашу не понял, ни деревьев не вижу, ни на картинках, ни в коде.

Comment: Данная задача представляет собой формирование дерева по индексам в соответствии с вложенностью элементов. Например: "Архыз" встречается в программе 490 раз в выходной структуре данный узел представляет собой корневой элемент parentId = 0 и записывается один раз. На него указывают остальные элементы в зависимости от повторов это: NL1 имеет parentId = 1 так как  Архыз ID = 1 он родительский элемент. Таким образом нужно строить структуру.

Comment: Это общие слова. Какая связь между первой таблицей и второй? Как, имея первую таблицу, получить вторую? Для меня это просто разные таблицы. Как дерево выглядеть должно? Вы можете хотя бы в паинте дерево нарисовать, как оно должно быть организовано?

Comment: Добавил картинку как оно должно выглядеть.

Comment: Код ваш вообще не понятен. что од делает? Вы открываете файл, что то читаете непонятными классами, потом бежите по каким то элементам и в цикле создаете узлы, но не все узлы добаляете в результат? Я вообще не понял, что происходит. Вы можете убрать из таблиц и кода всё лишнее? Можете подготовить пример, чтобы его можно было скопировать и локально у себя запустить?

Comment: У вас одни данные а первой талице, абсолютно другие данные во второй таблице и какие то третьи данные в дереве. Так не пойдет. Подготовьте [минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я примерно понял о чем речь. Так как автор не предоставил минимаьного примера, я сам придумаю данные на входе и выходе, но алгоритм должен быть понятен.

То, о чем вы пишете, можно решить при помощи структуры данных Trie, но я не хочу  усложнять пример, потому покажу не самый оптимальный, но работающий код.

Итак, пусть у нас будет узел дерева

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public List<TreeNode> Children {get;set;} = new List<TreeNode>();   
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public void Add(List<string> input, int index){
        if(index >= input.Count ) return;
        var value = input[index];

        TreeNode node = Children.FirstOrDefault(n=>n.Name == value);

        if (node == null)
        {
            node = new TreeNode() {Name = value};
            Children.Add(node);
        }

        node.Add(input, index+1);
    }
}
```

У него есть дочерние узлы и название. Также метод для добавления дочернего узла. На входе ему подается полный путь от верхнего узла до нижнего, и метод `Add` строит этот путь, если он ещё не был построен.

Как этот класс испольщовать?

```
var lst = new List<List<string>> {
    new List<string>(){"Архыз", "NL_1", "ID_73", "2 этап"},
    new List<string>(){"Архыз", "NL_2", "ID_73", "2 этап"},
    new List<string>(){"Архыз", "NL_2", "ID_72", "2 этап"},
    new List<string>(){"Архыз", "NL_2", "ID_72", "3 этап"},
};  

var root = new TreeNode();
foreach(var l in lst) root.Add(l, 0);

PrintNode(root);
```

Функция `PrintNode` просто выводит дерево в консоль

```
private void PrintNode(TreeNode node, string ident = "")
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{ident} {node.Name}");
    node.Children.ForEach(n=>PrintNode(n, ident + "    "));
}
```

На выходе получаем

```
 Архыз
     NL_1
         ID_73
             2 этап
     NL_2
         ID_73
             2 этап
         ID_72
             2 этап
             3 этап
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, что направили меня в нужную сторону)

Comment: @DENIS на здоровье